# Noetherian ring and prime ideal contained in an invertible maximal ideal.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, integral-domain, noetherian

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring which is an integral domain, and $M$ be an invertible maximal ideal. Suppose that $P$ is a prime ideal and $P<M$. How to show then that $P=PM$?

I was trying to say something about $PM^{-1}$ ($M^{-1}$ is an inverse of $M$), but still stuck.

Actually, my goal is to show that $P=0$, but this is an easy corollary to Nakayama's Lemma if indeed $P=PM$.

Answer (score 2):

A prime  invertible ideal $P$ in a noetherian domain $R$ has height one: this is proved in our friend's Pete Clark's great [commutative algebra notes](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mat.uniroma3.it%2Fusers%2Ffontana%2Fdocuments%2Fclarck-commutative%2520algebra.pdf&ei=vCirUtaSFsa60wWej4D4Dg&usg=AFQjCNHmjy1PI6dytaIrcRZz8k1AXfjADQ&sig2=Ml0kun1QUZkQGKkfwFVaOA&bvm=bv.57967247,d.d2k) as Proposition 19.22.
An immediate corollary is that a prime satisfying $P\subsetneq M$ must be zero and the step $P=PM$ is not needed.

If you know, and thus love!, algebraic geometry this is a consequence of the  correspondence between line bundles on a scheme and  divisors:  the point $[\mathfrak m]$ corresponds   to a divisor only if it has codimension one i.e. if $\mathfrak m$ has height one.

Comment: Thank you! That works fine.

Comment: But it order to fill the gap, is there any method to show that actually $B = BA$?

Comment: Dear user115454, since I find it pretty clear that $B=0$, I'm not going to spend much time trying to prove that $B=BA$ and then use Nakayama, which is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: Dear@user26857: no I don't mind, especially since I don't remember why I used the unfamiliar notation in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

We have $P=(PM^{-1})M$. We also have $PM^{-1}\subseteq MM^{-1}=R$, so $PM^{-1}$ is an ideal of $R$ and obviously $PM^{-1}\ne R$. Moreover, since $1\in M^{-1}$ we have $P\subseteq PM^{-1}$. Now use that $P$ is prime (different from $M$) and get (from $P=(PM^{-1})M$) that $P\supseteq PM^{-1}$, so $P=PM^{-1}$ or equivalently $P=PM$.

**Remark.** As the OP noticed, now it's easy to prove that $P$ must be in fact $0$. (Actually this part is the subject of [another topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555786/prove-that-in-a-noetherian-ring-no-invertible-maximal-ideal-properly-contains-a).)